# /dev/sda2 has gone 49710 days without being checked, check forced

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, centos

Why the shell show "/dev/sda2 has gone 49710 days without being checked, check forced." at centos start and then reboot?

......

/dev/sda2: Superblock last mount time is in the future.  FIXED.

/dev/sda2: Superblock last write time is in the future.  FIXED.

/dev/sda2 has gone 49710 days without being checked, check forced.

/dev/sda2:  REBOOT LINUX

Answer (score 9):

This indicates that the date recorded for the last check on that filesystem is in the near future (49710 days is very nearly 2<sup>32</sup> seconds, so it looks like a signed 32-bit number is being interpreted as ungisned).

Looks like you have clock issues. It may be your BIOS battery dead. On the software side, compare `hwclock` and `date` outputs. You might need to set the hardware clock (using `hwclock` tool for example), but first verify the battery state and replace if needed.

**Edit:** The issue looks to be well known. Google for *"49710 days" "check forced"* - it reveals links like [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg449770.html), or [this one](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.arch.general/15718) that clearly indicate the connection with system clock settings. The solution might be as simple as setting the hardware clock to UTC (as suggested in the second link), if the battery is ok.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the edit - yes, it looks more clear that way. I didn't mention the *near future* earlier because the observation was already made in [the other answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21585/dev-sda2-has-gone-49710-days-without-being-checked-check-forced/21587#21587).

Answer (score 7):

49710 days = 4294944000 seconds - which is eerily close to a round number, if you count in binary.

2^32 seconds is 49710.27 days - sounds like a timestamp for your filesystem's last check exploded somewhere along the line.  That may be a symptom of an issue with your drive - I'd recommend investigating further.

Comment: I'm with shane, I'd guess that last time your system fsck'ed the drive, the clock was somewhat in the future, and that "-0.27 days since last fsck, oh well" is being (rightly and properly) interpreted as "+49710 days, better do it now!".

Comment: Uhm... Google for *"49710 days" "check forced"*. It is not a coincidence. I bet the drive has nothing to do with it.

Comment: 49710 days, 6 hours, 28 minutes, 15 seconds is 0xFFFFFFFF when you use the calculation Days*24*60*60+Hours*60*60+Minutes*60+Seconds